# Permanently Disable Virtualization-Based Security (VBS) in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, amd-ryzen

I'm trying to disable [Virtualization-based Security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs) (VBS) so I can run [Ryzen Master](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/ryzen-master) and still use [WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/).

I've found this [Microsoft script](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337) which disables it fine but it doesn't persist between reboots. Secure boot is off in my BIOS. I've tried using Group Policy to disable it. This is a repost of [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1489224/windows-10-permanently-disable-vbs-virtualization-based-security) but it didn't get much traction and none of the answers seem to work.

*References*

- [WSL2 and Ryzen Master - Virtualization Based Security](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4771) (GitHub Issue)

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442486/6646109 answer. This worked for me on Windows 10 Pro. NOTE: Instead of DG_Readiness.ps1 -Disable please run DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable